# Question rollback and community wiki

Tags: support, questions, community-wiki

I've asked a question and after some edits I fatally and inadvertently changed it to community wiki.
Is it possible, using rollback, to return to the point where community wiki flag is not set?

Comment: I'm not in favor of deleting valid meta questions as dups of the faq. a faq is a laundry-list, and a specific question like this is much more likely to be found.

Comment: @Ros: Agreed that it should not be deleted, but it should still be closed.

Comment: Voting to close as "too localized" instead of "exact dupe" because the system no longer allows users to set their own questions to CW status.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

Once a post (either question or answer) is marked as community-wiki, that cannot be rolled back. Please see the appropriate [FAQ question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts/11741#11741).

If you're able to delete your question, you could do that and re-ask as non-CW.

Comment: I've just been informed that a mod can hit "remove wiki" in the mod menu on the question, however.  Just for those who see this answer and, like me, don't follow the link to the full version :P

Comment: how do i get to that link "remove wiki"?